# Advice on Java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

I am writing a UDP client program for my homework, and need a couple of advices for my implementation. The program is basically a word guessing game, where I send the word to the server and it responds with Correct/Incorrect. Multiple games can be run at the same time.

1) I want my main class to be the base interface, with a start new game button. Every time player hits start new game, I want a new thread to start with its own interface for the game. Does this sound right?

2) What would be the best way of managing those threads? A stack?

Thanks

Comment: those questions related to client or server side?

Comment: Client side. I am just supposed to send messages like gamestart, guess, showscore. Server responds with gameID, hints and T/F. Sorry if I was not clear in my question.

Comment: sorry, it isn't clear why you'd like to start a thread for every start game, usually, trying to server multiple users, the server need multi threading, but why would the client use them?

Comment: One of the requirements is to be able to start a new game while another one is in progress. I can track the games by gameID that the server sends in response of startnewgame message.

Comment: double check if its not a server requirement, otherwise this assignment is far from a real life situation

Comment: I am pretty sure I only have to do the client. Professor has supplied the sever. I got it working to the point where I send a startgame message and get the ID back. Every time I send the startgame, I get a different ID. Then I can request the word hint using the ID.